# mkdir -p ~ /.ssh returning Permission Denied

Tags: putty, linode

This is the very first time for me to start deploying website using Linode. So now I am following a tutorial and after creating a user in server I am trying to create a folder using `mkdir -p ~ /.ssh` but I keep receiving `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/.ssh’: Permission denied`

I am using Linode Ubintu and using Putty. So my question is why am I receiving this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space in your command:

```
mkdir -p ~ /.ssh
          ^ here
```

That space splits the path you wanted (`~/.ssh`) to the new 2 paths: `~` and `/.ssh`. Note that the second one is in the root (`/`) directory, which requires additional access rights to write in. But you most probably wanted to create `.ssh` in your home directory (to which the `~` leads), so proper command would be:

`mkdir -p ~/.ssh`